# Combine list elements to create a nested list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given a python list with alternating values of two types:

```
list = ['Q', '0.963', 'R', '0.020', 'K', '0.015', 'E', '0.001']
```

How can I combine every two values to get something like this:

```
new_list = [['Q', '0.963'], ['R', '0.020'], ['K', '0.015'], ['E', '0.001']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `range()`'s `step` parameter and list indexing.

```
list2 = ['Q', '0.963', 'R', '0.020', 'K', '0.015', 'E', '0.001']
new_list=[list2[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(list2),2)]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Q', '0.963'], ['R', '0.020'], ['K', '0.015'], ['E', '0.001']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and list slicing:

```
result = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2])]
```

Or just:

```
>>> list(zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]))
[('Q', '0.963'), ('R', '0.020'), ('K', '0.015'), ('E', '0.001')]
```